# Nginx load balancing based on URL and not IP address?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

We have concerns about load balancing based on IP for our service (for instance, a mobile client switching from 3G to Wifi). Is there a way to do it based on a part of a URL instead of by IP hash?

Answer (score 9):

Use the Upstream Consistent Hash module:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamConsistentHash

or Upstream Request Hash Module:

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamRequestHashModule

Comment: While this is certainly the best answer, I find myself wondering exactly /why/ you need this functionality.  Sticky sessions aren't required all that often, and when they are, they're almost always user-based.  I can't think of many situations where they would be URL based, since users frequently move page to page.

Comment: I think that the $request_uri is just used as an example in the nginx wiki, any variable can be used based on your needs

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and see if it works. @Scrivener the reason we need this is because it's for a real-time mobile video uploading service that we are planning on scaling horizontally. It's based on the POST URL endpoints.

Comment: Consistent Hashing is a technique commonly used when load balancing caches (so you don't have duplicated content on the cache, what means more space)

Comment: all linked pages redirecting to https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/ (so sort of dead)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way ([since 1.7.2](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#hash)) to achieve that is to hash a parameter in the incoming URL:

```
upstream upstream_name {
    hash $arg_loadBalancingToken consistent;
    server 192.168.1.2:1234;
    server 192.168.1.3:1234;
}
```

What does the trick is this part:

```
hash $arg_loadBalancingToken consistent;
```

It simply means that `nginx` will hash the argument `loadBalancingToken` in the query URL (in `https://yourserver.com/path?arg1=toto&loadBalancingToken=123`, it will hash the `123`), and balance the load depending on the result of this hash. You can replace `loadBalancingToken` with whatever name comes to your mind.
The `consistent` keyword is optional, and means that if one day you add or remove a server from the upstream, `nginx` will try to reallocate as few keys as possible. From the [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/):

> The optional consistent parameter to the hash directive enables ketama consistent‑hash load balancing. Requests are evenly distributed across all upstream servers based on the user‑defined hashed key value. If an upstream server is added to or removed from an upstream group, only a few keys are remapped which minimizes cache misses in the case of load‑balancing cache servers or other applications that accumulate state.

You could also decide to hash pretty much anything known to `nginx`.
The value of the cookie `toto`:

```
hash $cookie_toto [consistent];
```

All the arguments in the query:

```
hash $args [consistent];
```

Full list of what you can use is [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables).

Answer (score -1):

This may not exactly work for you, but 'balancing' by cname might be of interest to you.

```
server1    IN      A      192.168.0.101
server2    IN      A      192.168.0.102
www        IN      CNAME  server1
mobile     IN      CNAME  server2
```

Effectively, anyone who hits 'mobile.example.com' ends up asking server2 for data.  Then set up your user agent rewrite rules on sever1/www appropriately.